# setotherlanguage{arabic} makes inline-tikz not to be typset inline

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontspec, polyglossia, arabic

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{arabic} % comment that line, the problem disappears.

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
             Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,
                          Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}

\begin{document}
before tikz insertion  \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]\draw(0,0)circle(1ex); afteeeeeeeeeeeeer
\end{document}
```

I think it's specifically related to Arabic language, I also use Greek and Chinese, it does not affect `tikz`

[image: the buuuug]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably hidden use of math mode is forcing some direction nodes to intervene.
You can protect the code inside `\mbox`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{arabic} % comment that line, the problem disappears.

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
             Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,
                          Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}

\begin{document}
before tikz insertion  \mbox{\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\draw(0,0)circle(1ex);}} afteeeeeeeeeeeeer
\end{document}
```